# Setting checkbox state correctly

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, addition

I'm hoping I'm on the right track here....

I have some elements on my page (tables).. that are dynamically generated based on the results of querying a DB....  (I add  inside of a container DIV)..

inside these tables are some text..and a handful of checkboxes...  each table is the same (outside of the value of the text fields)..

When a user clicks on a checkbox.. I add an element to another container DIV off to the side.

If a user un-checks the checkbox.. it removes the element from the container DIV on the side. On each 'click' event..... I am also either adding or removing the 'selections' from an ARRAY (and also updating this array to my PHP SESSION)..

When the user is done.. they click a button and go to another page.. where this SESSION array is grabbed and reviews/summarizes their 'choices'..

*there is no FORM tags..  checkboxes are free-form in the tables (not wrapped in any FORM tags..so there is NO general POST action to grab everything.. hence the use of an array/SESSION)

If the user goes BACK to the original 'selection page' (with the tables/checkboxes)..

I am re-populating the PAGE (both re-checking any checkboxes...and re-populating the elements in the container DIV to the side..  all based on the SESSION data)

In each checkbox.. I am adding a little PHP function to write in checked="checked" or not.. when the checkboxes instantiate)

like so:

```
<label><input id="articlesnaming" name="Articles Naming Expert" type="checkbox" value="0.00" <?=sessionCheck($row["id"] ."-A","Articles Naming Expert") ?> onclick=""/>&nbsp;Articles Naming Expert</label>
```

FYI: on the function being called:

```
function sessionCheck($recordID, $checkBoxID){
    if(isset($_SESSION['userPicks']) && count($_SESSION['userPicks']) != 0){        
        for($r = 0; $r< count($_SESSION['userPicks']); $r++){
            if($_SESSION['userPicks'][$r]['recordid'] == $recordID){
                for($z=0; $z < count($_SESSION['userPicks'][$r]['itemsordered']); $z++){
                    if($_SESSION['userPicks'][$r]['itemsordered'][$z]['name'] == $checkBoxID){
                        return 'checked="checked"';
                    }else if($z == (count($_SESSION['userPicks'][$r]['itemsordered']) - 1)){
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            }else if($r == (count($_SESSION['userPicks']) - 1)){
                return "";
            }
        }
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Everything up to this point works fine...

Its when I go to dynamically build/add (append) those elements in the container DIV on the side... where problems happen.

I am getting them added just fine and when a user RE-VISITS the page.. previous checkboxes they had selected were/are checked again...  -and-.. the elements ARE in the container DIV to the side of the stage/screen)...

**PROBLEM:**  When I un-check one of the checkboxes, it DOES NOT remove the element in the container DIV on the side?   I have to re-click the checkbox..(which adds a duplicate).. then I can un-check it.. but it only removes the NEW one..

Everything seems to work fine until a refresh/re-visit of the page (and I have to automatically populate the checkboxes and the elements in the container DIV on the side).. then the checkboxes stop behaving/interacting with the elements that were adding through another function (still same ID's...paths..from what I can tell)....and -not- added through an initial checkbox event/action..

I am grasping at straws here....  it is perhaps because I'm using a PHP function to set the checkboxes on refresh?  and it maybe doesn't know its current state? (although the visual state of the checkbox is accurate/correct)

Any ideas are appreciated.

Code used to set/un-set checkboxes & add/remove elements from the side container DIV :

```
<script>
//var to hold current check box clicked
var targetCheckbox;
//var to hold cumulative total
var totalPrice = 0;
//array to keep track of user picks from returned record results

//try to get SESSION array (if available/set) from PHP into jQuery using json_encode()
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['userPicks'])){ ?>
    //overwrite jQuery userPicks MAIN array
    var userPicks = <?php echo json_encode($tempArray) ?>;
<? }else{ ?>
    //create new jQuery userPicks MAIN array, and populate through user clicks/interaction
    var userPicks = [];
<? } ?>

$(document).ready(function() {
    //check to see if seesion and populate checks and side column from previous picks
    //if existing session, loop through and populate the CHOICES column
    if(userPicks.length > 0){
        console.log("SESSION EXISTS, POPULATE CHOICES COLUMN FROM ARRAY");
        for(i=0; i<userPicks.length; i++){
            //build up sub array data first then append at one time.
            var subArrayLength = userPicks[i].itemsordered.length;
            var subArray = '';
            for(s=0; s<subArrayLength; s++){
                subArray += '<li id="' + userPicks[i].orderid + userPicks[i].checkboxid + '">' + userPicks[i].itemsordered[s].name + '</li>';
            }           
            $("#choicesWrapper #itemList").append('<div class="recordChoices"><h5>CASE NAME: '+userPicks[i].casename+'</h5><ul id="'+userPicks[i].recordid+'">'+subArray+'</ul></div>');            

        }
    }

    //onClick event
    $('.orderOptions').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function () {

        //routine when checkbox is checked
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {               
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
            console.log("checked");

            //console.log('doesnt exist..create it');
            $("#choicesWrapper #itemList").append('<div class="recordChoices"><h5>CASE NAME: '+caseName+'</h5><ul id="'+resultsID+'"><li id="'+orderID+targetCheckbox+'">'+itemOrdered+'</li></ul></div>');
        }else{          
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            console.log("un-checked");

            //remove the option from right column (li element)  
            console.log("REMOVE TARGET: #choicesWrapper #itemList #"+resultsID+" "+orderID+targetCheckbox);
            $("#choicesWrapper #itemList #"+resultsID+" #"+orderID+targetCheckbox).remove();


            //check if no more children and remove parent/title (record container/div)          
            if ($("#choicesWrapper #itemList #"+resultsID+" li").length > 0) { 
                //console.log("Still has children...do nothing");               
            }else{
                //console.log("No Children...");
                $("#choicesWrapper #itemList #"+resultsID).parent().remove();               
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Oddly enough, when things are 'auto-populated' from the SESSION data (like on refresh or re-visiting the page) and when things 'break', unchecking the checkboxes doesn't remove things, but when I uncheck the very last checkbox in a group, it does remove the parent (so that parent removal code/routine is being executed...but not then child  )

I'm thinking this is a pathing issue?  (I believe I am creating things with exactly the same ID's/classes...etc).

Definitely worth the +1 if you answer! :)

The only other thing I can think of is.. HOW the userPicks array gets created.. initial visit to page, I just create an empty JS/jQuery array and wait to push/populate it when a user clicks a checkbox (code above for onClick stuff).

But when a user visits the page (refresh or re-visit) and -HAS- (previous) SESSION data still available....  then I grab the PHP SESSION array.. and pass it to jQuery using `json_encode()`...

Do I need to add/delete from that array differently than I do if I created normally?

Comment: Can you add the JS that's adding / removing the div's?

Comment: yes....  added to main post.  Its a bit trimmed up (stuff that does pertain to this like prices,..etc)

but thats the 'gist' of it.  Its basically 3 aspect/states where things get either added or removed from the stage (and setting matching checkboxes)


1.)if user is refreshing or re-visiting the page..and there is already a SESSION array of previous choices..  I pass my SESSION data to my JS/jQuery...loop through the array and add my elements to the side DIV.

2.)If user manually clicks checkbox

3.)If user manually un-checks checkbox

* I also re-set checkboxes using PHP code above.

Comment: I don't suppose there's somewhere that the code is online that could be looked at while working?

Comment: sorry...Its not on-line, to be viewed.. (at least currently, I'd have to strip out some stuff to make it viewable)

god news is work through my errors (for the most part).. I found why I couldnt target the elements to remove them...  which led to another duplication error.. which is now fixed as well..

my last problem to address is.. when I go 'back' to my page now... (from visiting another page)....  the DB query stuff is executed again.. (but since all search form fields are empty...it does a 'generic' search and returns everything!).. I need to figure out how to: get previous search result